# Can I use a field name which contains a period (".") in my data source for ag-grid?

Tags: json, ag-grid

I have a data source which contains fields with periods in their name. e.g.

```
[{
   "id": 1234,
   "OD.name": "Andrew",
   "OD.age": 21
},{
   "id": 1235,
   "OD.name": "Roofus",
   "OD.age": 22
}]
```

However, when I bind this to the grid the values for columns which contain periods in their field names are not rendered. Is this a known bug/not-supported in ag-grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure that **suppressFieldDotNotation** is set to **true**.

From the ag-grid reference
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/

> If true, then dots (eg address.firstline) in field names are not
>   treated as deep references. Allows you to use dots in your field name
>   if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The field name is going to be interpreted by the grid as an expression, so if you provide a field name.of "OD.name", it will try to find the "OD" property of your data row, and then try to find the "name" property of that. Of course, that's not going to work.

However, you can supply a "valueGetter" function in your column definition, which will be responsible for supplying the value to the grid. In that function, you can do whatever you need to do to get the value from the row and return it.